# Зашумленные данные

Tags: машинное-обучение, статистика

Требуется генерировать зашумленные данные. Какие статистические методы зашумления существуют? Мне только известно о гауссовском шуме, но он подаётся определенному закону распределения.

Comment: Очень странное замечание про то, что гауссовский шум не подходит по причине того, что он "подаётся" закону распределению. Это говорит о том, что вы вообще не понимаете, о чем идет речь -  советую хоть учебник какой прочитать, что-ли. Потому что ЛЮБОЙ шум, в том числе и те, которые вам показали в якобы ответе и которые вы непонятно почему за ответ вдруг приняли (учитывая указанное замечание) "подаются"  какому-либо распределению.  Ну и про "методы" зашумления -  вам показали только один из них, аддитивный. А может быть как минимум еще и мультпликативный.  Вы в учебник все-таки загляните.

Comment: Какой учебник посоветуете? Просто я видел, что существуют statistical noise и random noise, поэтому на каком-то интуитивно уровне мне показалось, что различие в них как раз в законе распределения. Буду признателен за пояснение и какую-либо инфу.

Comment: Все зависит от того, что и зачем вы зашумляете. Можно зашумлять данные с целью обеспечения их защиты (например от утечки), можно зашумлять видеоряд  чтобы "сбить с толку" систему распознавания, можно накладывать шум на фото для создания эффекта. Если это временной ряд,то шум можно накладывать во временном представлении сигнала, а можно в спектральном и т.д.  Я не знаю, ради чего вы решили зашумлять свои данные.

Comment: Поэтому могу посоветовать начать с любого нормального учебника по статистике и теорверу. Хоть с Вентцель, хоть с Гмурмана.  Или вот -  неплохая водная статья именно про анализ и моделирование шумов: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/introduction-to-statistical-noise-analysis-basic-calculations/

Comment: Зашумить данные нужно, чтобы потом исследовать такие синтетические данные в машинном обучении на объектах разной природы: звуки, "точки", временной ряд, изображения и т.д.  И такой глупый вопрос: для всех таких объектах одинаково будет работать один и тот же метод зашумления?

Comment: Если вы будете использовать один и тот-же метод на всех объектах, то построенные вами системы ML и будут нормально работать только в случае, если ваши реальные объекты включают именно этот единственный вид шумов. А поскольку реальные шумы никогда не будут в точности соответствовать шумам синтезируемым и могут оказаться очень разнообразными по своей природе -  то тем самым вы существенно ухудшаете качество ваших моделей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из известных мне генераторов шумов могу выделить [Uniform Noise](https://aishack.in/tutorials/generating-uniform-noise/), [Shot noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shot_noise)  и [Exponential noise](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277398/how-to-explain-exponential-plus-gaussian-noise)
Примеры реализации на питоне:

**Uniform**

```
import numpy as np

def add_uniform_noise(data, amplitude=0.1):
    noise = np.random.uniform(low=-amplitude, high=amplitude, size=data.shape)
    noisy_data = data + noise
    return noisy_data
```

**Poisson**

```
import numpy as np

def add_poisson_noise(data, scale=1):
    noisy_data = np.random.poisson(data * scale) / scale
    return noisy_data
```

**Exponential**

```
import numpy as np

def add_exponential_noise(data, scale=1):
    noisy_data = data + np.random.exponential(scale, size=data.shape)
    return noisy_data
```

Comment: Ответ не соответствуют вопросу. Вас спросили о "методах зашумления", а не об известных вам законах распределения. Кстати, как-то мало законов вам известно.  В модуле np.random, который вы используете, существует около 35 генераторов случайных чисел. А в scipy.stats -  около 100 генераторов непрерывных распределения и более 20 -  дискретных. И все они могут использоваться для "зашумления".

Comment: @passant ответ формировал по своему опыту и по примерам по которым когда то сам учился, во всяком случае ответ был прянят, а значит я помог) А по поводу количества можно сказать что угодно, но это не значит что в практике все использовали именно эти 35-100-20 постянно.